# Click a button in second life menu automatically

Tags: linden-scripting-language

i recently started to play Second Life and I would like to know if there is a way to write a program outside of SL viewer that allow to click on sl menu's button automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless You really feel like writing Your own 3rd party viewer. The only time I've seen this done is through SmartBots, but even that is using a custom coded viewer to host the bot.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use external programs such as AutoHotkey to do clicks at certain locations on-screen.

Do note that [all UI elements in SL viewer are drawn not using the OS's GUI component system, but actually drawn by SL viewer itself using OpenGL calls](https://community.secondlife.com/forums/topic/494498-viewer-feature-request-world-view-in-separate-window/#comment-2544425), so you'll have to do coordinate calculations yourself, and click at certain relative coordinate to the viewer's window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).